# VirtualBox won't re-install after unintsall

Tags: install, virtualbox

I am running Big Sur. I recently installed VirtualBox and tried to load a CentOS image from OSBoxes. I basically restarted my laptop, forgot about it for more than 30 minutes after installation and then tried to load the CentOS image. I got the error "virtualbox error kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)". After searching for it, it appeared to be a Security Issue. However, I never got a Security notification asking me to allow apps from Oracle. The preferred solution was to uninstall VirtualBox and then re-install it and get the security notification. I uninstalled VirtualBox using the uninstall script which comes with the installer. However, the re-installation is failing when I try to install. It is giving me the error "Installation Failed. Contact the manufactured for assistance". I temporarily disabled Mac Gatekeeper, but I never get any notification asking me to allow installations from Oracle. Could you please help?

Comment: So Big Sur is still in *beta* which means lots of things can and will break for no apparent reason. I would search out your symptoms in relation to Big Sur on the VBox discussion boards. There may even be a whole discussion just about Big Sur compatibility that you may want to peruse.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about a non updated app using kernel extensions on a beta OS. I would expect it to fail. Ask the apps authors what to do

Comment: Good day everyone. We don’t close questions on beta software or just rare combinations of software. Unless there are other quality reasons to close this, it is on topic, subject wise.  @mmmmmm your comment actually shows there is an answer to this, validate version compatibility so the question seems clear enough to answer IMO.

Comment: This has worked for me. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410530/323181